Quotient of the plane by the standard Cremona involution
Consider the standard Cremona involution $i:\mathbb{P}^2\dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$, $[x:y:z]\rightarrow [yz:xz:xy]$.
Let $Y$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in the three base points of $i$, so that $i$ lifts to an automorphism $\widetilde{\imath}:Y\rightarrow Y$, and $X := Y/\left\langle \widetilde{\imath}\right\rangle$ the quotient of $Y$ by the action of $\widetilde{i}$.
What kind of surface is $X$? Can it be described explicitly?

$i$ is a birational involution, so what do you mean by the quotient?

I made my question more precise.

There is no such thing as the standard involution; the answer to your question depends very much of the way you write it. For instance, the way you define it, $i$ fixes the curve $y^2=xz$, while the usual form has only 4 fixed points. The quotient surface will be different in each case.

What's the usual form form you?

For me the standard form maps $[x:y:z]$ to $[yz:xz:xy]$ (what you wrote is not actually an involution).

As noted by user @abx the form in my comment has four fixed points which give rise to four ordinary double point singularities on the quotient surface.

I see. Do you have an explicit description of the quotient surface?

What do you want to know, precisely?  It is a log del Pezzo surface with four $A_1$ singularities.  It had an embedding in $\mathbb{P}^5$ as a codimension two subvariety of $\text{Sym}^2(\mathbb{P}^2)$.  If you want the defining equations, you can get them from a computer algebra program.

The quotient surface is the cubic
$$
u_0u_1u_2 + u_0u_1u_3 + u_0u_2u_3 + u_1u_2u_3 = 0, 
$$
the only cubic with four nodes.
EDIT. To see this one can first observe that the involution acts biregularly on the sextic del Pezzo surface and has exactly 4 fixed points. It follows that the quotient is a suface with ample anticanonical class of degree $6/2 = 3$ with 4 nodes. Finally, there is only one such cubic surface up to isomorphism, and the above equation gives it.

Thanks. How did you get this equation?

I added some explanation to my answer.
